# Carousel Transition - Automatic + Prev/Next - Additional effect

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

For information, i'm a beginner in coding. : - )
I use this code https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp from W3Schools to put in place my carousel.

I added to the basic slideshow (with arrow next/prev) an automatic transition after 5 seconds, but when I click on prev or next, it adds the transition effect on automatic transition effect. It looks like a nightclub party.

I don't know how to execute the effect one time by action (click). Below is the modified JS I use.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```html
<!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/75/50/animals" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/75/50/animals" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/75/50/animals" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>
```

Do you have an idea ?
Many thanks !

Ludovic

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you added `setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);` to the `showSlides` function call so it will create another `setTimeout` call on each click making them seem to be faster. You need to remove the old timeout if the function is getting called before it is finished (as in when a click happens on the next slide button). I ignored the dots you can figure that one for yourself based on this example I assume.

I only show the lines I changed to get this working:

```
function plusSlides(n) {
  // remove the slideIndex += n as showSlides automatically updates slideIndex
  showSlides();
}

var slideTimer = null;

showSlides() {
  // clear the timer so it doesn't fire too many times
  if (slideTimer !== null) {
    clearTimeout(slideTimer);
    slideTimer = null;
  }

  /* rest of your code */

  slideTimer = setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}
```

Once you figure out how this implementation is working, I'd suggest to make your own by not keeping the slide index as variable in JS but by checking which is the current active slide.